# Cutomize select box have with large option box

Tags: css

I have a select box like

[image]

But when I use the select box in css, it looks like below

[image]

how to get the large option box and width have to cover upto text.

Comment: You can add customized CSS to enlarge the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it in the css file.
HTML:

```
<div >
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select:</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And in css you add:

```
select, option {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: after added width to select and option width increased but how to move the options box to left most like image what share before

Comment: I think the dropdown box is handled by the browser, If you would like to fit it under the text you probably have to use javascript or some other language that allows you to build a custom dropdown. maybe this helps a bit.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212587/drop-down-list-issue)